# Swift 2.0 How to detect that the user holds instead of just tapping

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I am looking for a way to detect if the user is holding on the screen (Holding the screen for 1 second) I tried using a timer but i did not work. Here is the code i have right now.

```
var brakeTimer = NSTimer()

func update () {
    print("The user is holding the screen")   
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    var brakeTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    brakeTimer.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for an [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Holding" on the interface is commonly referred to in iOS development as "Long Pressing". Here's how to set up one of those :

```
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressed:")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

func longPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        println("longpressed")
    }
```

As opposed to a simple tap recognizer, which will fire when the user simply taps on the screen rather than holding for a longer duration of time.

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapped:")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    func tapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        println("tapped")
    }
```

Comment: You can also use a timer between the press of a finger and release but using LongPress as suggested here is better for most uses.

Comment: @Jeremiah yeah I guess timing the difference between UITouchDown and UITouchUpInside, something like that?